# Changing the Shape of an existing Node in MxGraph

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

In MxGraph, I am able to decide the shape while creating the node, but once it is created I am unable to change its shape. I couldn't find the respective API to update the Graphs for the existing Nodes.

Is it possible to achieve with the existing API or Do I need to write work around to do the same?

Comment: Could you supply some code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to hold the shape in the style and change the style

```
var defaultStyle = this.getDefaultVertexStyle();
defaultStyle[ mxConstants.STYLE_SHAPE ] = "YOUR-SHAPE-NAME"; // must be registered in the stencil registry

var alternateStyle = // create a new style object here, with a different mxConstants.style_shape
graph.getStylesheet().putCellStyle("alternateName", alternateStyle")
```

now  you can change the style and the shape will change

PS: it's all off the top of my head so the functions might not be exactly named like that